# Edit a file via a script yet maintain the osx tags

Tags: shell-script, files, osx, xattr, tagging

On OSX you can have tags which allows you to identify different categories of files. Here are two text files with different tags when viewed in Finder:

[image]

I have a large number of these files and have written a bash script to make several edits on these files. So, for instance I do:

```
$ sed 's/old text/new text/' file1.txt > /tmp/foo.txt
$ cp -p /tmp/foo.txt file1.txt
```

in which case I get the desired file content but loose the tags:

[image]

**Question**:
How do I copy the tags from the original file to the edited file?

Comment: I believe that in this specific use case you can use "sed -i" for inline editing. This will keep tags in place. Not posting as answer as it doesn't answer part about copying tags and you can't always use inline editing.

Comment: @pbm: I was not able to get the "sed -i" to work on MacOS 10.9.5 and still keep the tags. The "-i" required a file extension that was used to rename the current file and hence the meta data was lost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run `> /tmp/foo.txt`, you are overwriting the *contents* of `/tmp/foo.txt` with the output of `sed 's/old text/new text/' file1.txt`. Since `/tmp/foo.txt` doesn't exist when you run this command, bash will create that file for you and then write it.

Then, when you use the `-p` flag to `cp`, you are copying the permissions and attributes of `/tmp/foo.txt` to `file1.txt` and overwriting it in the process.

Instead, what you want to do is overwrite the contents of `file1.txt` with the contents of `/tmp/foo.txt`, which should sound familiar. Run

```
sed 's/old text/new text/' file1.txt > /tmp/foo.txt
cat /tmp/foo.txt > file1.txt
```

Note that this doesn't copy any permissions or attributes from `file1.txt` to `/tmp/foo.txt` or vice versa - you are maintaining the existing metadata for `file1.txt`, but modifying the content.

In this specific instance, you could also just use `sed -i` as pbm suggested.

Comment: Glad it was so simple.